# Activate Stripe Checkout after Form Validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

Disclaimer: I am very new to this and I'm helping someone develop a website, and am running into an issue. They bought a theme and I'm struggling to understand everything that is happening when the event occurs.

**Here's what's happening** (code at the end).

I'm collecting registration and payment on my /register.php page. I have a form (collecting name, email, phone, etc). I want to have a submit button that, when pressed, saves the information to a secure csv file and then shows the Stripe Checkout. I should note that I do want to use Stripe Checkout because I feel like end users will feel more secure seeing this.

The problem comes with form validation. The page uses jQuery.validate.js which I assume is a standard js script, and a custom one called form-validation.js. The form calls on process-form.php, where I have it save the data to a csv file. The problem is in activating Stripe Checkout from here.

Stripe's default comes with a button that is injected at run-time. I have created a second button (and hidden them both) that is identical save for an id="customButton". I wanted to use javascript to click this button from either the form-validation.js page or the process-form.php page, but none of this is working.

I have tested the button and it works in and of itself, but the stripe checkout never pops up.

Here's the relevant bits of my code.

**register.php**

```
                            <div class = "form-group"> 
                            <span class = "highlight"><h3>$30</h3></span>
                            Full-Access Day Pass
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="delegateName" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Full Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="delegateName" id="delegateName" placeholder="Jack Smith">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control required email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="jack.smith@illuminatevancouver.com">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstchoice" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">First Choice</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control required" name="firstchoice" id="firstchoice" placeholder="Select your first workshop choice">
                                        <option value="Entrepreneurship" selected>Entrepreneurship</option>
                                        <option value="Technology" >Technology</option>
                                        <option value="Personal Branding" >Personal Branding</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="secondchoice" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Second Choice</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control required" name="secondchoice" id="secondchoice" placeholder="Select your second workshop choice">
                                        <option value="Entrepreneurship" selected>Entrepreneurship</option>
                                        <option value="Technology" >Technology</option>
                                        <option value="Personal Branding" >Personal Branding</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="grade" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Grade</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control required" name="grade" id="grade" placeholder="Select your grade">
                                        <option value="8 - 9">8 - 9</option>
                                        <option value="10 - 11" selected>10 - 11</option>
                                        <option value="12 or above">12 or above</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="school" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">School</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required " name="school" id="school" placeholder="Sauder School of Business">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cellPhone" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Cell Phone</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required number" name="cellPhone" id="cellPhone" placeholder="778 123 4567">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="emergencyContact" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Emergency #</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required number" name="emergencyContact" id="emergencyContact" placeholder="778 987 6543">
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="meal" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Meal</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <select class="form-control required" name="meal" id="meal" placeholder="Select your meal type">
                                        <option value="Non - Vegetarian" selected>Non - Vegetarian</option>
                                        <option value="Vegetarian" >Vegetarian</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="other" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Other</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " name="other" id="other" placeholder="Allergic to Dairy">
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" name = "payNow" value = "Pay With Stripe"></input>
                        </form>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
<div class = "hidden/"
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-amount="3000" data-description="All-Access Day Pass"></script>

          <button type = "submit" class = "stripe-button-el" id = "customButton">Custom Button</button>
</form></div>
```

**form-validation.js**

```
// Form validation - register form
    toastr.options = {"positionClass": "toast-top-full-width"};
    $('.form-register').validate({
      messages: {
        fullname: "Please enter your fullname",
        password: {
          required: "Please provide a password",
          minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        confirmPassword: {
          required: "Please provide a password",
          minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
          equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
      },      
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        var $this = $(form);
        $.ajax({
          url: $this.attr('action'),
          type: 'POST',
          data: $this.serialize(),
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
          if( msg == 'ok' ) {
            toastr.success('Thanks for signing up! Expect an email soon from auto-confirm@illuminatevancouver.com.');
            $this[0].reset();
          } else {
            toastr.error('An error occured. Please try again later.');
          }
        })
        .fail(function() {
          toastr.error('An error occured. Please try again later.');
        });
      }      
    });
```

**process-form.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('/config.php');
   $varDelegateName = $_POST['delegateName'];
   $varemail = $_POST['email'];
   $varFirstChoice = $_POST['firstchoice'];
   $varSecondChoice = $_POST['secondchoice'];
   $vargrade = $_POST['grade'];
   $varschool = $_POST['school'];
   $varcellPhone = $_POST['cellPhone'];
   $varemergencyContact = $_POST['emergencyContact'];
   $varmeal = $_POST['meal'];
   $varother = $POST_['other'];

   $fs = fopen("delegateData.csv","a");
  fwrite($fs,$varDelegateName.", ".$varemail.", ".$varFirstChoice.",".$vargrade.",".$varSecondChoice.",".$varschool.", ".$varcellPhone.", ".$varemergencyContact.", ".$varmeal.",".$varother."\n");
  fclose($fs);



  echo "ok";
  exit;


?>
```

The code I am using to call the button is `document.getElementById("customButton").click();`
Which I think is uncontroversial. In PHP it's wrapped with an echo as

```
echo'<script type = "text/javascript"> document.getElementById("customButton").click(); </script>';
```

If I am missing anything, you can see everything at illuminatevancouver.com/register.php